# How to show json data as optgroup with multiple-select in Select Option in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I try to show JSON data as optgroup option with multi-select in angularjs but not get success

In Html it shown as:

```
<select ng-model="industrycatslect" ng-change="industryslected(industrycatslect)" multiple   ng-options="skilldata.value as skilldata.value group by skilldata.group for skilldata in skillCategory track by skilldata.id">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
</select>
```

JSON shown as:

```
"skillCategory": [
        {
            "id": "8",
            "group": "Technology",
            "value": " Software Engineering"
        },
        {
            "id": "17",
            "group": "Technology",
            "value": "Collaboration and Content Management"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "group": "Functions",
            "value": "Procurement"
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "group": "Functions",
            "value": "Product"
        }
    ],
```

Please Help me I think I done some mistake in "ng-options".

Comment: Looks like you have not posted full code of HTML and controller. Working for me like charm: https://plnkr.co/edit/AzanFFHxqgXm4f2X40X8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much changes except removing the `track by` part

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
    $scope.skillCategory = [
        {
            "id": "8",
            "group": "Technology",
            "value": " Software Engineering"
        },
        {
            "id": "17",
            "group": "Technology",
            "value": "Collaboration and Content Management"
        },
        {
            "id": "22",
            "group": "Functions",
            "value": "Procurement"
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "group": "Functions",
            "value": "Product"
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <select ng-model="industrycatslect" multiple ng-options="skilldata.value as skilldata.value group by skilldata.group for skilldata in skillCategory">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
  </select>
  
  <br>
  {{industrycatslect}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I face a new problem that I am not able to get the selected data id. Please help

Comment: @Neotrixs You can change to `ng-options="skilldata.id as...` to fill the result array with id's, or use `ng-options="skilldata as...` to fill the result array with all the information from data source.

Comment: Thanks, Your really save my day.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might help you out. There was an error in how you define your `skillCategory` JSON data. I hope that this JSFiddle helps out. It's not sorted by ID but it displays the elements as intended:

[Answer 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/725/)